# Bootstrap validator error message with bootstrap alert

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

This is the code were i am using to validate fields but i want to show all error message with popup of left bottom.I am tired to implement popup for these all error message.

```
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" data-error="Please Enter Name" required>
<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
</div>


<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<input type="text" pattern="^[_A-z0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="inputTwitter" placeholder="Phone Number" data-error="Please Enter Phone Number" required>
<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
</div>

<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Bruh, that email address is invalid" required>
<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<input type="password" data-minlength="6" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"  data-error="Enter Password" required>

<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPasswordConfirm" data-match="#inputPassword" data-match-error="Whoops, these don't match" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<select id="" name="user_interest" class="form-control" required="">
<option value=""> Select Passion</option>
<option value="Actor">Actor</option>
<option value="Art">Art</option>
<option value="Dancing">Dancing</option>
<option value="Education">Education</option>
<option value="interest">interest</option>
<option value="Lyrics">Lyrics</option>
<option value="Rap">Rap</option>
<option value="Writer">Writer</option>
</select>
<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<select id="" name="user_school" class="form-control" required="">
<option value=""> Select School/College</option>
<option value="DLF">DLF</option>
<option value="DPS">DPS</option>
<option value="LPS">LPS</option>
<option value="RLB">RLB</option>
</select>
<span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-inline text-left">
<div class="radio radio-primary">
<input type="radio" name="usertype" id="Guru" value="option1" required>
<label for="Guru">Guru</label>
</div>

<div class="radio radio-primary">
<input type="radio" name="usertype" id="Mentor" value="option2" required>
<label for="Mentor">Mentor</label>
</div>  

<div class="radio radio-primary">
<input type="radio" name="usertype" id="User" value="option2" required>
<label for="User">User</label>
</div>      

</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-inline text-left">
<div class="radio radio-primary">
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="Male" value="option1" required>
<label for="Male">Male</label>
</div>

<div class="radio radio-primary">
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="Female" value="option2" required>
<label for="Female">Female</label>
</div>                                
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group hidden">
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="terms" data-error="Before you wreck yourself" required>
Check yourself
</label>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group text-center">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit <i class="fa fa-fw fa-unlock-alt"></i></button>
</div>
</form>
```

This is the code were i am using to validate fields but i want to show all error message with popup of left bottom.I am tired to implement popup for these all error message. Please anyone can help me

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle please, so we can help you?

Comment: sure 
Here is the example link https://jsfiddle.net/Navtosh/6pe64pfs/ i want to show error in popup box in the windows left bottom

Comment: 1. Your reference `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/validator.js` blocked with forbidden message. You need to find another url. 2. You can use `$('#myForm').validator()` because you have not `$('#myForm')` in your page. Please fix those and we will continue from there.

Comment: It's working properly but i want to show error not with the field related too.
i want to show errors left bottom of the screen. You know what i am trying to say

Comment: If I understand what you want, you need to add to the form the attribute `novalidate` to prevent the html5 validation. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_novalidate.asp. Am I write?

Comment: no no no wait i am attaching image that u can understand properly what i wan to say

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87864/discussion-between-navtosh-adhikari-and-mosh-feu).